# Descoberta de classes para novas entradas a partir de um treinamento já realizado

Tags: aprendizagem-de-máquina, weka

Uma vez treinado o Weka, usando para classificação o J48, p.ex., como, a partir daí (passos a serem realizados), aplicar o modelo treinado sobre novos dados de entrada, de modo que as classes dessas entradas sejam gerada pelo sistema/modelo treinado?

```
@relation sentido    % xx atributos 

@attribute sentar {sim, não}
@attribute sentado {sim, não}
@attribute carro {sim, não}
@attribute bicicleta {sim, não}
@attribute avião {sim, não}
@attribute barco {sim, não} 
....    
@attribute assento {sim, não}     % classe

@data
não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não
não,não,sim,sim,não,não,sim,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,sim
não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não
...
```

**Dada, p.ex., essa nova entrada, preciso q o sistema informe a classe a q pertence**:

```
não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,não,sim,não,não,não,não,?
```

Comment: Eu vi aqui que WEKA é uma tecnologia. Desconsidere meu comentário anterior.

Comment: Você deve salvar o modelo treinado. Quando quiser utilizar novamente, basta carregar o mesmo.